# Run Google Cloud Build in a specific region and zone?

Tags: google-cloud-build

Is it possible to specify to run a Google Cloud Build in a specific region and zone?

The documentation seems to outline how to run a kubectl in a specific region/zone for deploying containers, but it doesn't seem to document where to run the cloud build itself. I've also not found this setting in the automatic build trigger configuration.

Answer (score 5):

The latest public doc on regionalization can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/locations

---

(Earlier answer on this topic follows)

This is not yet an available feature, however, at Google Next we announced an EAP / soon to be Alpha feature called "Custom Workers" which will enable this functionality for you. You can watch the demo here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IUKCbq1WNWc&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Thanks for the link, this was very interesting! What I haven't found in the documentation was where this shared worker pool is running and I wanted to set in which shared worker pool our build would be running. I'm primarily concerned about this because I was thinking about network egress being charged for storage accessed by the builds when the storage is in another region from the shared worker pool.

Comment: There is no documentation for this yet because it is not yet Generally Available. (still in EAP) Watch our release notes for a product announcement: https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/release-notes

Comment: @DavidBendory - there hasn't been a lot of activity since October 2018. Any update on when this will be available in Cloud Build?

Comment: Hey, please send an email to cloud-build-contact@google.com, we'd be happy to put you in touch with our Product Manager and put you on the Alpha waiting list.

Comment: cloud-build-contact@google.com is deprecated.  the autoresponse recommends https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/support