# Cloud build avoid billing by changing eu.artifacts.<project>.appspot.com bucket to single-region

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-app-engine-python, google-cloud-build

Using app engine standard environment for python 3.7.

When running the `app deploy` command are container images uploaded to google storage in the bucket `eu.artifacts.<project>.appspot.com`.

This message is printed during `app deploy`

```
 Beginning deployment of service [default]...
#============================================================#
#= Uploading 827 files to Google Cloud Storage              =#
#============================================================#
File upload done.
Updating service [default]...
```

The files are uploaded to a multi-region (eu), how do I change this to upload to a single region?

Guessing that it's a configuration file that should be added to the repository to instruct app engine, cloud build or cloud storage that the files should be uploaded to a single region.

Is the `eu.artifacts.<project>.appspot.com` bucket required, or could all files be ignore using the `.gcloudignore` file?

The issue is similar to this issue [How can I specify a region for the Cloud Storage buckets used by Cloud Build for a Cloud Run deployment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60982068/how-can-i-specify-a-region-for-the-cloud-storage-buckets-used-by-cloud-build-for), but for app engine.

I'm triggering the cloud build using a service account.

Tried to implement the changes in the solution in the link above, but aren't able to get rid of the multi region bucket.

```
substitutions:
  _BUCKET: unused
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['app', 'deploy', '--promote', '--stop-previous-version']
artifacts:
  objects:
    location: 'gs://${_BUCKET}/artifacts'
    paths: ['*']
```

Command `gcloud builds submit --gcs-log-dir="gs://$BUCKET/logs" --gcs-source-staging-dir="gs://$BUCKET/source" --substitutions=_BUCKET="$BUCKET"`

Comment: Did you try creating a bucket the region that you want and added the flag  --bucket=BUCKET [1]? https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy

Comment: @AndieVanille Tried it with a different named bucket but that caused duplication, files uploaded both to the `--bucket=<name>` and the `eu.artifacts.<project>.appspot.com`. If I wish to create a bucket named `eu.artifacts.<project>.appspot.com` then I need to verify the domain name, which google created for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigation a little bit more, I want to mention that this
kind of bucket is created by the “container registry” product when you deploy a new container( **when you deploy your App Engine Application**)-> When you push an image to a registry with a new hostname, Container Registry creates a storage bucket in the specified multi-regional location.This bucket is the underlying storage for the registry. Within a project, all registries with the same hostname share one storage [bucket](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/overview#registry_name).

Based on [this](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/securing-builds/set-service-account-permissions#pull_private_images_from_others), it is not accessible by default and itself contains container images which are written when you deploy a new container. It's not recommended to modify it because the artifacts bucket is meant to contain deployment images, which may influence your app.

Finally, something curious that I found is when you create a default bucket (as is the case of the aforementioned bucket), you also get a staging bucket with the same name except that staging. You can use this staging bucket for temporary files used for staging and test purposes; it also has a 5 GB limit, but it is automatically emptied on a weekly [basis](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/setting-up-cloud-storage#activating_a_cloud_storage_bucket)

Comment: So is there anything you *can* do? I also seem to be getting billed for usage of this bucket.

Answer (score 2):

I delete whole bucket after deploying, which prevents billing

```
gsutil -m rm -r gs://us.artifacts.<project-id>.appspot.com
```

`-m` - multi-threading/multi-processing (instead of deleting object-by-object this arguments will delete objects simultaneously)

`rm` - command to remove objects

`-r` - recursive

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rm