# Can I change default Cloud Storage bucket region used to store artifacts while deploying Cloud Functions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

### What I'm doing

I'm deploying `Cloud Functions` using `Cloud Source Repositories` as source using the `gcloud` command line like this:

```
gcloud functions deploy foo \
--region=us-east1 \
--source=<repoUrl> \
--runtime=nodejs12 \
--trigger-http
```

This process behinds the scene triggers `Cloud Build` that uses `Cloud Container Registry` to store its images and also creates some buckets in `Cloud Storage`.

### Problem

The problem is one of those buckets `us.artifacts.<projectName>.appspot.com` that is a multi-regional storage which incurs additional charges compared to a regional storage and doesn't have a free tier to use.

The others bucket are created in the same region as the function (`us-east1` in my case)

### What I'd like to know

1. If I can change the default region for this artifacts bucket
2. Or, if it's not possible, what I can change in my deployment process to avoid these charges.

### What I've already tried or read

1. Some users had [similar problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63578581/firebase-storage-artifacts) and suggested a lifecycle rule to auto-clean this bucket, also in the same post some users didn't recommend to do it because it may break the build process
2. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62151198/cloud-build-avoid-billing-by-changing-eu-artifacts-project-appspot-com-bucket) we had an answer explaining the behind the scenes of an `App Engine` application deployment that also creates the same bucket.
3. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60982068/how-can-i-specify-a-region-for-the-cloud-storage-buckets-used-by-cloud-build-for) may solve my problem but I'd need to setup `Cloud Build` to trigger a build after a commit in master branch.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You do realize the difference in pricing is six-tenths of a penny. For 10 GB that is $0.06. To answer your question, no you cannot change the storage class.