# How to set Region or Location when deploying to Cloud Run?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deployment, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-run

I would like to deploy an application (as a container image) to Google Cloud Run. I am following the documentation as below:

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy

I would like to set the region as Tokyo (asia-northeast1) for the following commands:

```
gcloud builds submit

gcloud run deploy
```

The reason is that Cloud Run and Cloud Storage costs depends on the region. I would like to set the location of Cloud Storage and Cloud Run.

Comment: Since you are using the `gcloud run deploy` command, add the command-line option `--region=asia-northeast1`.

Answer (score 7):

Setting the Cloud Run deployment region prior to deployment with gcloud is covered in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/setup):

> Optionally, set your platform and default Cloud Run region with the
> gcloud properties to avoid prompts from the command line:
>
> ```
> gcloud config set run/platform managed
> gcloud config set run/region REGION
> ```
>
> replacing REGION with the default region you want to use.

Comment: Thank you for your help. What about Cloud Storage (where the container is saved?)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60982068/how-can-i-specify-a-region-for-the-cloud-storage-buckets-used-by-cloud-build-for

Answer (score 4):

When creating a service in Cloud Run Console there's a region dropdown in Service setting see the image below :

[image]

you can also use the `gcloud` command to specify the region:

```
gcloud run deploy --image gcr.io/PROJECT-ID/DOCKER --platform managed --region=asia-northeast1
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. What about Cloud Storage (where the container is saved?)

Comment: It seems your question and concern are similar to @DougStevenson [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60982068/14356364). Have you visited the question and the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60983361/14356364)